# How to use `-isysroot` of clang properly?

Tags: c, clang, llvm

Here's my directory structure:

```
clang-sysroot
\-sysroot
  \-usr
    \-include
      \-perqin.h
\-test.c
```

In test.c:

```c
#include <perqin.h>
```

If I run `clang -c test.c -o test.o`, the compilation will fail, as the compiler doesn't know where to find perqin.h.

So I try adding isysroot argument:

```
clang -isysroot "C:\...\clang-sysroot\sysroot" -c test.c -o test.o
```

But it still fails.

Did I misunderstand the usage of `-isysroot`? If so, how can I specify the sysroot correctly?

For detailed screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you try `--sysroot` instead of `-isysroot` to see if it works?

Comment: `--sysroot` works. However in some cases one might want to only influence headers. Looks like that's an old clang bug: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11503